# Disable caps lock key

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings, caps-lock

I have a new MacBook Air and I keep bumping the <kbd>caps lock</kbd> key. As you can imagine this is really frustrating.

Is there a way to totally disable the <kbd>caps lock</kbd> key without having to install software or mucking around with Terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via System Preferences.

More specifically:

1. Go to Apple > System Preferences…
2. Click on the Keyboard pane
3. At bottom right click on the <kbd>Modifier Keys…</kbd> button
4. Now click on the Caps Lock button to select the No Action option
5. Exit System Preferences

Comment: THIS DOES NOT DISABLE THE F%&%/&ING CAPS LOCK KEY FOR NON-APPLE KEYBOARDS ATTACHED.